# How to debug prototype jquery function

Tags: jquery, json

I have this jquery function code and i don't know why it don't return response nor show any error in the console.
I've written alerts to debug it but it don't get to none.

```
BxTimelineView.prototype._getPosts = function(oElement, onComplete)
{
    var $this = this;
    var oData = this._getDefaultData(oElement);

    jQuery.get(
        this._sActionsUrl + 'get_posts/',
        oData,
        function(oData) {
          alert("HERE!")         
            if(typeof onComplete === 'function')
               {
                return onComplete(oData);
                  alert("NOW!")  
               }
                
            if(oElement) {
                $this.loadingInBlock(oElement, false);
                  alert("THEN!")  
            }
            
            processJsonData(oData);
            alert("GO!")  
        },
        'json'
    );
};
```

My json data is broken too, [here](https://www.avren.co.il/m/timeline/get_posts/?view=timeline&type=public&owner_id=275&start=2&per_page=2&per_page_default=2&timeline=0&filter=all&name=&browse=list&status=active&dynamic_mode=false&_t=1595614415666) it has a bug inside that making the function to break down, so if i can debug the function i can fix the json bu escaping things

Comment: You can use [debugger](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) statements to force the break. And you can use `console.log(x)` to get more helpful debug statements in the console.

Comment: jQuery get returns a promise which gives you more callback options should the server return non-success https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/#jqxhr-object.

Comment: If i could rewrite its equivalent in JavaScript....